# clone one interface in another of the same type in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, interface, clone

I want to make a copy of one object of one specific type of interface with another of the same interface, here i will write 2 class examples and their output.

This is class Vehicle:

```
#ifndef _VEHICLE_
 #define _VEHICLE_


class Vehicle {
public:
    Vehicle(int a): val(a) {}
    virtual ~Vehicle() {}
    virtual void setVal(int i) = 0;
    virtual int getVal() = 0;
protected:
int val;

};

#endif
```

This is class Car

```
 #ifndef _CAR_
 #define _CAR_
#include "Vehicle.h"

class Car : public Vehicle {
public:
    Car(int a) : Vehicle(a) {}
    ~Car() {}
    virtual void setVal(int i);
    virtual int getVal();
};

#endif
```

The two methods of the class car just return the value and modifies it like the names suggest.

This is the code of the main

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "Vehicle.h"
    #include "Car.h"

    using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Vehicle * car1 = new Car(0);
    Vehicle * car2 = new Car(1);
    cout << "val car1 :"<< car1->getVal() << endl; 
    cout << "val car2 :"<< car2->getVal() << endl; 
    car1 = car2;
    cout << "val car1 :"<< car1->getVal() << endl; 
    cout << "val car2 :"<< car2->getVal() << endl; 
    car2->setVal(6);
    cout << "val car1 :"<< car1->getVal() << endl; 
    cout << "val car2 :"<< car2->getVal() << endl;
    car1->setVal(-1);
    cout << "val car1 :"<< car1->getVal() << endl; 
    cout << "val car2 :"<< car2->getVal() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
val car1 :0                                                                                                                                                                                                          
val car2 :1

val car1 :1                                                                                                                                                                                                          
val car2 :1 

val car1 :6                                                                                                                                                                                                          
val car2 :6  

val car1 :-1                                                                                                                                                                                                         
val car2 :-1
```

As you can see, there are two different objects of the same interface, but as both objects must be pointers because it is an interface, it´s impossible to make just a copy of the object instead of assign the pointer of the "car2" to the "car1".

My question is if there is any way of doing this, or i just need to make a "clone" method.

thank you for the attention, and sorry if the question is very basic, but i am starting with C++ and some things are a little complicated.

Yes i tried to make a reference instead of a pointer but it gives the next error:
 [error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Vehicle&' from an rvalue of type 'Car']

It talks about to make a const reference, but i think its impossible to make a copy of one const object. By the way, this is just code i made in 5 mins to make the question more clear, the real problem is a class full of vectors and other objects ( very big, thats why i am avoiding the clone() method )

**SOLVED! After making the overload of "=" the exception was a null pointer of the auxPop, i made some new constructors and now it works. Thanks to all!**

Comment: You need a `clone` method.

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm starting to think about they want to have a `std::shared_ptr<Vehicle>` actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
*car1 = *car2;
```

derefrence those pointers to operate on the actual objects. I forget to count my stars all the time. This will invoke the default copy function, if you make a class more complicated then just a single integer however, you may want to add an explicit copy function, written like this;

```
class Car : public Vehicle
{
    ...
    Car& operator=(const Car& eql);
    ...
}

Car& Car::operator=(const Car& eql){
    val = eql.val;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
car1 = car2;
```

The above is wrong since `car1` memory has not been deleted.
instead you delete `car1` first:

```
delete car1;
car1 = car2;
```

If you want to copy car2 into car1 so that they don't point to the same chunk of memory you can make an asignment operator:

```
class Car {
public:
    Car& operator=(const Car& other)
        {
            this->val = other.val;
            return *this;
        }
};
```

In case of assign operator u don't have to delete 1st pointer, the 1st object gets overwriten

```
    *car1 = *Car2; // assign objects, not pointers
```

Now Cars won't interfere with each other, finally destroy Cars..

```
delete car1;
delete car2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a clone() method, but it's more like Java way. In C++ you'd rather use a copy constructor. When you don't specify one, the compiler creates it, like so:

```
 Vehicle(const Vehicle& a): val(a.val) {}
 Car(const Car& a): Vehicle(a) {}
```

Note: you also can create them yourself if u need to do something other than just copy content.

Then you can use these constructors like so:

```
 Vehicle* a = new Car(1); // new object
 cout << a->getVal() << endl; // prints 1

 Vehicle* b = new Car(a); // here create a copy of a
 cout << b->getVal() << endl; // prints 1

 a->setVal(3);
 cout << a->getVal() << endl; // prints 3
 cout << b->getVal() << endl; // prints 1
```

Also: Do not forget to use `delete` when you create objects with `new`:

```
 delete a;
 delete b;
```

In your code you don't delete `car1` before reassign pointer with `car2`, causing a memory leak.